# How to pass in multiple values to convert parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am wanting to add an addition message to my tooltip in my code, but I think I would need an additional parameter to pass in to the ConverterParamater.  This is what I currently have for my XAML.

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}, ConverterParameter='Original Value: {0}', RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string temp = "{0}";

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            temp = parameter.ToString();
        }
        return string.Format(temp, value);
    }
```

I would like to add a new string to my converter parameter that would also take in a different variable.  But I don't know if that is possible since Path cannot take in more than one value.

Comment: This can be done with a [MultiBinding](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/12/wpf-multibinding-example.html#.V17Qp6KZBPs)

Comment: If the multiple parameters involve bindings that will be updated at runtime, I would use a [multivalue converter with a multibinding](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2154/simple-example-of-multibinding-and-imultivalueconverter-in-mvvm-wrt-wp). If the parameters are all constants known at design time, I would derive my converter from `MarkupExtension`, and give it a named, typed public property for each parameter. Then use it like so: `Converter={local:StringConverter Length=34,ShoeSize=12,Etc='whatever'}"`.

Comment: Thanks @Funk. I'm surprised I never knew that existed.